# Getting "Invalid value" when testing android in-app purchase with static response

Tags: google-api, android-inapp-purchase

I get an error when making test request for verifiyng android in-app purchase (billing) from my server.
I use one of the following products (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#billing-testing-static):

> There are three reserved product IDs for testing static Google Play Billing responses:
>
> **android.test.purchased** 
> When you make an Google Play Billing request
> with this product ID, Google Play responds as though you successfully
> purchased an item. The response includes a JSON string, which contains
> fake purchase information (for example, a fake order ID).
>
> **android.test.canceled** 
>  When you make an Google Play Billing request
> with this product ID Google Play responds as though the purchase was
> canceled. This can occur when an error is encountered in the order
> process, such as an invalid credit card, or when you cancel a user's
> order before it is charged.
>
> **android.test.item_unavailable** 
>  When you make an Google Play Billing
> request with this product ID, Google Play responds as though the item
> being purchased was not listed in your application's product list

I make a GET HTTP request as described (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.gigantic.clawee/purchases/products/android.test.purchased/tokens/inapp:com.gigantic.clawee:android.test.purchased?access_token=<MY_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

but get an error in response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid",
        "message": "Invalid Value"
      }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid Value"
  }
}
```

What did I do wrong? Please, help. I

Comment: Hi I had same problem but was testing with real product, in my case the product purchase token was wrong.